# Using TFVC in the windows terminal

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2019, tfvc

I am working in a company that uses TFS integrated with visual studio as their version control system. We are using a windows machine. Due to some potential accessibility problems (I am blind and using a screen reder), I'd like to explore the possibility of using TFVC in the CLI, like what I usually do in Git. Git is totally accessible for blind users due to fact that we can do anything in the terminal (the windows CLI is fully accessible to screen readers).

The main reason why I want to do this is: I am a beginner in TFVC, and so a little concerned if the UI of visual studio (with regards to integrating with TFS) is fully accessible with screen readers or not. If not, I can at least go and use it in the terminal instead.

Is it possible to run and execute TFVC commands (checkin, checkout) in the terminal just like what we do in git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to operate TFVC from a console.

You need the `tf.exe` command (which is installed with VS).

There is documentation of the various sub-commands [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-command?view=azure-devops).